# CPPCheck: Errors in local header files are not caught

Tags: cmake, cppcheck

I have a project that uses CMake with a top level CMakeLists which references subdirectories each with their own targets and CMakeLists. Each subdirectory includes `src`, `include` dirs.

I'm trying to execute Cppcheck on my code base using the following command:

`cppcheck --project=compile_commands.json --suppressions-list=suppressions.txt --output-file=cppcheck-results.log --xml --enable=all`

My suppressions.txt file contains a bunch of style errors to skip.

The problem is that it doesn't catch any error/issue in local .h files (inside the include directories).

Unless I specify cppcheck to check a specific directory and give the -I flag, then it would. But for the whole project it does not.

Comment: Have you tried adding the local.h to your cmake target? Althoug  not necessary for building, it might be necessary for the compile_commands.json database. Also do you include local.h witn ""? If you use <> cppcheck might mistake it for a system header

Comment: @arved The header files are not added to add_executable() but rather as traget_include_directories(). Might this be the reason that cppcheck ignores them? Also the hearders are included in the src files with `#include "filename.h"` whereby the path is resolved from CMake.

Comment: In include_directories you have the directories. The header files you can optionally add to add_executable